# "Would be no" vs "would not be a/an"

Tags: grammar

Do "**would be no"** and "**would not be a**" mean the same in the following context? And do they sound natural?

- If I were elected the president, There **would not be a** clash between communities regarding religion.
- If I were elected the president, There **would be no** clash between communities regarding religion.

Can any teacher or anyone who has knowledge of the langusge please answer this?

Answer (score 2):

Either is acceptable. The "no" variant is less common, perhaps even rare in informal contexts.